# How can I turn a column that includes a video into a row on mobile devices?

Tags: html, iframe

I have this piece of code here that shows an embedded youtube video beside a paragraph of text on my website.

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%; display: table;">
<div style="width: 60%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; margin: 10px;">
Text Goes Here
</div>
<div style="width: 40%; display: table-cell; margin: 10px;">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fJ9rUzIMcZQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

This works as intended on computers, however when it comes to mobile devices the structure obviously doesn't change and we can see a small video player beside a very narrow text.

How can I make it so that the video goes below the text specifically just on mobile devices or narrow browsers? The usage of iframe seems to limit what I want to achieve but I can't think of another way of including an embedded youtube video.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal you need mediaqueries that you use to visualize the elements separately depending on the screen size. So you can make and adapt your own visualizations for each device. You can find a great contribution to mediaqueries and how they work here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp